# Air trapped behind check valve?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, hot-water

I recently installed a thermostatic mixing valve on the hot water feed to my shower pump which has a max water temp. (One of these https://www.commercialwashroomsltd.co.uk/assets/docs/products/TMV3_Spec_sheet.pdf ) This has an integral check valve.

However I seem to have an air lock in the system. I can clearly hear the water *trickling* down the mixed outlet. Is it possible that this is cause by air trapped behind the check valves? Is this even physically possible? I have tried draining and refilling the system to try and remove the air.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

About the system: Gravity fed. Dedicated supply to the mixer valve from both the hot water cyclinder and cold water tank which feeds into the shower pump that feeds just one shower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to remove the cold water feed downstream of the check valve and remove the air from the mixed pipe using the hot water feed. I then reattached the cold feed. There is probably still a small amount of air in there but it doesn't noticeable impact the flow.